# what package should I use for $\mathscr{C}$?

Tags: fonts, packages, code, sourcecode

What package should I use for `$\mathscr{C}$` to function? any help will be appreciated.

My LaTeX file contains this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}



\title{Topology}
\author{MM}
\date{February 2, 2020}



\maketitle

\section{Problem(I)}\\

\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

But it does not work with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A font that gives nice (in my extremely humble opinion, the nicest) `\mathscr{}` is given by the `mathrsfs` package. There are many others...

Answer (score 9):

To use `\mathscr`, you can use the `mathrsfs` package as already mentioned. I think it is also worth mentioning the [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) package, which allows to use several different math script fonts.

Here's a small example with the `mathalpha` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=rsfs]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\texttt{scr=rsfs}:     \(\mathscr{C}\)
\end{document}
```

The above code loads the `rsfs` script font, but using another `scr` option when loading the package will give a different font. For example, here are the results with three different options:

[image]

Several other options are listed in the [package documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If you have the error about the package named 'mathalpha',
I recommend the package named 'mathalfa' with the same package option '[scr=~~]'.

Comment: @JeongSeonYeom In fact, both are the same package: `mathalfa` is just the old name of `mathalpha` (see the [page](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha) of the package on CTAN). If your LaTeX distribution is up to date, any of these two names loads the same package.